# Eduroam on Aquaris E4.5 (Ubuntu edition)

Tags: wireless, ubuntu-touch, smartphone

Is there any possibility to use eduroam on Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition? If this is the case what is the proper way to install eduroam on this device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution to the problem. Follow the instructions on http://www.danbishop.org/2015/02/21/add-eduroam-or-any-other-802-1x-wireless-network-to-ubuntu-phone/. My modified eduroam profile will be created like this:

```
printf "[ipv6]\nmethod=auto\n\n[connection]\nid=eduroam\nuuid=89feacc0-bf73-48b1-92bf-3fb57b735c89\ntype=802-11-wireless\n\n[802-11-wireless]\nssid=eduroam\nsecurity=802-11-wireless-security\n\n[802-1x]\neap=ttls;\nidentity=<YourID>\nanonymous-identity=anonymous@uni-greifswald.de\nca-cert=/etc/ssl/certs/Deutsche_Telekom_Root_CA_2.pem\nphase2-auth=pap\npassword=<YourPassword>\n\n[ipv4]\nmethod=auto\n\n[802-11-wireless-security]\nkey-mgmt=wpa-eap\n" > eduroam
```

Final command was:

```
sudo chown -R root:root /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eduroam
```

Restart the phone and then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a working eduroam profile from a laptop (in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections), remove the mac address-line, and transfer that file to your phone. I did have to change two fields in that file:

```
eap=ttls
```

and

```
phase2-auth=pap
```

Move eduroam profile file to appropriate location on your phone:

```
sudo mv eduroam /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
```

and own it by root:

```
sudo chmod 600 /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eduroam
```

This made eduroam work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use Aquaris E4.5 (Ubuntu edition). For me the following settings for the network manager on the phone worked:

Wireless Security : WPA & WPA2 Enterprise

Authentification  : PEAP

Anonymous Id      : (none)

Certificate       : (none)

PEAP Version      : Version 0

Auth. protocol    : MSCHAPv2

user name         : your_login

password          : your_password